# AVL tree implementation on python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am doing a coding assignment on implementing AVL tree in python but get stuck. The assignment only requires us to perform the insertions of elements and the predecessor query. As it is an assignment, the teacher requires us to build the code from scratch.

The logic of my code is simple. I just define one class called Node. Whenever elements are inserted into the tree, I will perform a rotation if needed. However, an error appears in the RLrotation() method where there is a statement B = c.rightchild. The error message said that c is "None" so it has no attribute "rightchild". However, the error appears after more than 170,000 insertions so I don't know how to debug.

Moreover, I think my implementation is too complicated. The assignment allows a maximum running time of 10seconds but I think mine can't achieve that. I wonder if anyone could suggest how I can improve my code.

Thanks a lot for the help!

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, key, parent):
    self.key = key
    self.parent = parent
    self.leftchild = None
    self.rightchild = None
    self.height = 1

  def insert(self, element):
    if element < self.key:
      self.insertleft(element)
    else:
      self.insertright(element)

  def insertleft(self, element):
    if self.leftchild != None:
      self.leftchild.insert(element)
    else:
      self.leftchild = Node(element, self)
      node = self
      self.height = 2
      while node.parent != None:
        node = node.parent
        if (node.rightchild != None) and (node.leftchild != None):
          if node.leftchild.height - node.rightchild.height > 1:
            node.leftrotate()
            return 0
          elif node.rightchild.height - node.leftchild.height > 1:
            node.rightrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 1+max(node.leftchild.height, node.rightchild.height)
        elif node.leftchild == None:
          if node.rightchild.height == 2:
            node.rightrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 2
        else:
          if node.leftchild.height == 2:
            node.leftrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 2

  def insertright(self, element):
    if self.rightchild != None:
      self.rightchild.insert(element)
    else:
      self.rightchild = Node(element, self)
      node = self
      self.height = 2
      while node.parent != None:
        node = node.parent
        if (node.rightchild != None) and (node.leftchild != None):
          if node.leftchild.height - node.rightchild.height > 1:
            node.leftrotate()
            return 0
          elif node.rightchild.height - node.leftchild.height > 1:
            node.rightrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 1+max(node.leftchild.height, node.rightchild.height)
        elif node.leftchild == None:
          if node.rightchild.height == 2:
            node.rightrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 2
        else:
          if node.leftchild.height == 2:
            node.leftrotate()
            return 0
          else:
            node.height = 2

  def leftrotate(self):
    if self.leftchild.leftchild == None:
      self.LRrotation()
    elif self.leftchild.rightchild == None:
      self.LLrotation()
    elif self.leftchild.leftchild.height == self.height-1:
      self.LLrotation()
    else:
      self.LRrotation()

  def LLrotation(self):
    u = self.parent
    a = self
    b = self.leftchild
    B = b.rightchild
    C = a.rightchild
    a.parent = b
    a.leftchild = B
    if B != None:
      B.parent = a
    b.parent = u
    b.rightchild = a
    if u != None:
      if u.leftchild == a:
        u.leftchild = b
      else:
        u.rightchild = b
    if (B == None) or (C == None):
      a.height = 1
    else:
      a.height = 1+max(a.leftchild.height, a.rightchild.height)
    b.height = 1+max(b.leftchild.height,b.rightchild.height)

  def LRrotation(self):
    u = self.parent
    a = self
    b = self.leftchild
    c = b.rightchild
    B = c.leftchild
    C = c.rightchild
    a.parent = c
    a.leftchild = C
    b.parent = c
    b.rightchild = B
    c.parent = u
    c.leftchild = b
    c.rightchild = a
    if B != None:
      B.parent = b
    if C != None:
      C.parent = a
    if u != None:
      if u.leftchild == a:
        u.leftchild = c
      else:
        u.rightchild = c
    if b.height == 2:
      b.height = 1
    a.height -= 1
    c.height = a.height +1

  def rightrotate(self):
    if self.rightchild.rightchild == None:
      self.RLrotation()
    elif self.rightchild.leftchild == None:
      self.RRrotation()
    elif self.rightchild.rightchild.height == self.height-1:
      self.RRrotation()
    else:
      self.RLrotation()

  def RRrotation(self):
    u = self.parent
    a = self
    b = self.rightchild
    B = b.leftchild
    C = a.leftchild
    a.parent = b
    a.rightchild = B
    if B != None:
      B.parent = a
    b.parent = u
    b.leftchild = a
    if u != None:
      if u.rightchild == a:
        u.rightchild = b
      else:
        u.leftchild = b
    if (B == None) or (C == None):
      a.height = 1
    else:
      a.height = 1+max(a.leftchild.height, a.rightchild.height)
    b.height = 1+ max(b.leftchild.height,b.rightchild.height)

  def RLrotation(self):
    u = self.parent
    a = self
    b = self.rightchild
    c = b.leftchild
    B = c.rightchild
    C = c.leftchild
    a.parent = c
    a.rightchild = C
    b.parent = c
    b.leftchild = B
    c.parent = u
    c.rightchild = b
    c.leftchild = a
    if B != None:
      B.parent = b
    if C != None:
      C.parent = a
    if u != None:
      if u.rightchild == a:
        u.rightchild = c
      else:
        u.leftchild = c
    if b.height == 2:
      b.height = 1
    a.height -= 1
    c.height = a.height +1

  def query(self, value, result):
    if self.key == value:
      return value
    elif self.key > value:
      if self.leftchild != None:
        return self.leftchild.query(value, result)
      else:
        return result
    else:
      result = self.key
      if self.rightchild != None:
        return self.rightchild.query(value, result)
      else:
        return result
```

Comment: The statement `B = c.rightchild` indeed looks dangerous. But I see that you used that same construction in each of your 4 rotation functions ... And why do you need 4 rotation functions? In the 80s we only needed 2 rotation functions for an AVL tree, if I remember correctly ...

Try to make a drawing of the tree. And try to figure out how the top nodes and branches are supposed to rotate, if the tree becomes unbalanced ...

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. For the LR and RL case, they need to perform double rotation and I try to do it at once. Maybe I should separate it can try to see if I can get rid of the error. Thanks!